# Free tool to simplify parcel shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, ogr, open-source-gis

Is there any tool available which let's me run millions of parcel shapefiles and simplify them?

Comment: what do you mean by simplify, the edge?

Comment: I think I would be concerned about running simplify on polygons without some type of topology. I don't even think esri will manage two edges being simpplified simultaneously so they remain consistent. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try Shapely - a Python API built on top of [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/). As both Shapely and GDAL have Python libraries you can easily [combine them to data from many different sources](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-shapefile-geometries-fields-save-load.html) (including shapefiles) and then simplifying and exporting as desired.

The only downside may be speed if you are doing millions of features - it could be faster to use GEOS or [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm) directly.

See the [simplify](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html#constructive-methods) method:

> All points in the simplified object
>   will be within the tolerance distance
>   of the original geometry. By default a
>   slower algorithm is used that
>   preserves topology. If preserve
>   topology is set to False the much
>   quicker Douglas-Peucker algorithm
>   is used.

```
>>> p = Point(0.0, 0.0)
>>> x = p.buffer(1.0)
>>> x.area
3.1365484905459389
>>> s = x.simplify(0.05, preserve_topology=False)
>>> s.area
3.0614674589207187
```

Answer (score 17):

Version 9.0 of GDAL/OGR added the -simplify option to the [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command. The documentation indicates that it preserves topology.

> -simplify tolerance:
>   (starting with GDAL 1.9.0) distance tolerance for simplification. This method will preserve topology, in particular for polygon geometries.

Example usage:

```
ogr2ogr outfile.shp infile.shp -simplify 0.000001
```

Answer (score 8):

If your data is stored in PostGIS, try using [ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html).

Answer (score 6):

ogr2ogr has a "segmentize" option that appears to do what you need:  [GDAL ogr2ogr documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

From that page:

> -segmentize max_dist:
>   (starting with GDAL 1.6.0) maximum distance between 2 nodes. Used to create intermediate pointsspatial query extents

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Mapshaper](http://mapshaper.com/test/demo.html). There are maybe some limitations due to your file size.

Answer (score 5):

GRASS v.generalize

http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/v.generalize.html

Comment: I made some test and as of today, all methods suggested here and relying on GEOS (ogr2ogr with -simplify, shapely, PostGIS's ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology function) produce topological anomalies (i.e. holes/overlaps between polygons). Only with GRASS I had good results.

Answer (score 3):

Inspire from Mapshaper, but directly in local, look on https://github.com/migurski/Bloch

Comment: thanks for your response. I guess the issue here is what to do if no topology is define with the shapefile